# nvidia cuda 7.5 driver in tensorFlow are not properly handled (ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: cuda, gpu, tensorflow

After a an install without pb, I am trying the tutorial about GPUs : 
I type :

```
with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
  a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3], name='a')
  b = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[3, 2], name='b')
  c = tf.matmul(a, b)
  print(c)
  sess.run(c)
```

I got :

> Tensor("MatMul_1:0", shape=TensorShape([Dimension(2), Dimension(2)]), dtype=float32, device=/gpu:0)

.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in
>     File "/home/olivier/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 345, in run
>       results = self._do_run(target_list, unique_fetch_targets, feed_dict_string)
>     File "/home/olivier/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 419, in _do_run
>       e.code)
>   tensorflow.python.framework.errors.InvalidArgumentError: Cannot assign a device to node 'b_1': Could not satisfy explicit device specification '/gpu:0'
>        [[Node: b_1 = Constdtype=DT_FLOAT, value=Tensor, _device="/gpu:0"]]
>   Caused by op u'b_1', defined at:
>     File "", line 3, in
>     File "/home/olivier/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/constant_op.py", line 147, in constant
>       attrs={"value": tensor_value, "dtype": dtype_value}, name=name).outputs[0]
>     File "/home/olivier/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1710, in create_op
>       original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
>     File "/home/olivier/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 988, in **init**
>       self._traceback = _extract_stack()

In Torch7, my GPU works normally

Comment: I managed to have it working by adding the path to cuda drivers 7.0 at the end of  LD_LIBRARY_PATH.              export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/olivier/digits-2.0/lib/cuda"

Comment: if that is your solution, please add it as an answer to the question

Answer (score 4):

The binaries published by google need to find `libcudart.so.7.0` in the path library , you just need to add it to  `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` by something like

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/olivier/digits-2.0/lib/cuda"`

that you put in your `.bashrc`

Answer (score 0):

On an optimus laptop (running Manjaro Linux) it's possible to run TensorFlow with cuda acceleration by starting a python console with optirun:

```
$optirun python
```

I detailled the way to do it [here](https://dip4fish.blogspot.com/2016/03/using-tensorflow-07-from-python-on.html).